# Are tires on one side of my car mounted in the wrong direction?

Tags: tires

I am wondering if the tires on one side of my car are mounted in the wrong direction. The picture below shows the front wheels, the left one and the right one.

[image]

If you look at the thread, you may notice that the direction is the same. I would expect that from *front and back* wheels on the same side but not from *left and right* wheels.

In other words, when I go around the car and look at the tires, all of them look exactly the same from outside; the thread indicates that all of them should be rotating clockwise. Obviously, that means the wheels on the left side should be rotating backward at the same time as the wheels on the right side should be rotating forward (judging by the pattern on the tire)...

By the way, all four tires have the word "outside" on the outside wall but there are no arrows indicating rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotation Direction, and Outside (vs Inside) are two different things.

Rotation Direction is indicated by the arrow.  Outside is indicated by the word "Outside".

Rotation direction-specific tires have a generally symmetric sort of "V" look to them when viewed from the front or back of the vehicle.  Tires marked "Outside" are generally asymmetric when viewed the same way.

[image]

Comment: So in my case I have two asymmetric tires facing the same way on one axle. This feels like if I put my hands in front of me on the table and both would be left. Is that normal? Using your picture, I would have two identical copies of the left tire on one axle. I would then expect that I would drift away to one side if I hit a really big puddle; would I not?

Comment: Imagine the aggressive side of the asymmetric tire above is marked "Outside".  Then if you got on your knees in the front your car, and looked back at and under the car, you'd see the two tires on the car's left (driver's) side looking like the asymmetric  tire above.

Comment: "So in my case I have two asymmetric tires facing the same way on one axle. " Um...  You indicated you have "Outside" printed on the outside of both tires on the front of your car. That means they are not facing the same way (say both towards the driver's side) but rather they are both pointing to the OUTSIDE of the car.

Comment: I do not quite get the logic, but it indeed seems that not all tires there days have a direction of rotation; what you are saying can also be found at Tire Rack blog post ["Are my Asymmetric Tires Running Backwards?"](https://blog.tirerack.com/blog/hunters-ramblings/are-my-asymmetric-tires-running-backwards). Thus +1 (and accept a little later just to see if anyone else wants to chip in).

Comment: Tire Rack is a great resource.

Comment: Perhaps my language is misleading; it is not my native tongue. Both of the front (or back, for that matter) tires have "Outside" on the outside. But they indeed all look as if they would rotate clockwise when looking from outside. The problem is, what is clockwise looking from the driver's side becomes counter-clockwise when looking from the passenger side. Regardless, it seems this should not be a problem. If the tire designers think it is OK, then it is OK with me :)

Comment: @RichardHardy - As mike is stating, if the tire had "outside" marked on the outside, that's the way they should be fit. I think you're in good shape here.